# Threejs when parent matrix change, children does not applied

Tags: javascript, three.js

When the matrix is ​​applied to the parent object, I want the child object to be applied as well.

```
//set transformmatrix
const m = new THREE.Matrix4();
m.elements = [...];

//parent
var Parent = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(30, 30, 30, 10);
var colortex = new THREE.Color();
colortex.setRGB(255, 0, 0);

var MatParent = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: colortex,
    metalness: 0,
    roughness: 0,
});

var MeshParent = new THREE.Mesh(Parent, MatParent);
scene.add(MeshParent);

//child
var Child1= new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(100, 64, 32);
var MatChild1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: colortex,
    metalness: 0,
    roughness: 0,
});

var MeshChild = new THREE.Mesh(Child1, MatChild1);

MeshParent.add(MeshChild );
MeshChild.position.x = 0;
MeshChild.position.y = 0;
MeshChild.position.z = 200;

MeshParent.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
MeshParent.geometry.applyMatrix(m);
MeshParent.updateMatrix(true);
```

**Before matrix apply**

[image]

**After matrix apply**

[image]

As image show, after apply matrix, cylinder object moved, rotated by x-axis. However child object isn't worked. I want to child object is placed to red-circle I draw.

Anyone give me advise please. Thank you for read.

sorry for image upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MeshParent.geometry.applyMatrix(m);

Transforming the geometry of a 3D object has no effect on the descendants's transformation. So you have to change the `position`, `rotation` or `scale` properties. Or alternatively, set `matrixAutoUpdate` to `false` and modify `Object3D.matrix` directly. Just keep in mind that in this case, you don't want to call `updateMatrix()` (since you already set it manually).